# What are the four Dutch exclusive cards in Munchkin Koethulhu?

Tags: munchkin

*Munchkin Koethulhu*, the Dutch language version of *Munchkin Cthulhu*, consists of the translations of *Munchkin Cthulhu*, *Munchkin Cthulhu 2: The Call of Cowthulhu*, and *Munchkin Cthulhu 3: The Unspeakable Vault*, along with 4 exclusive Dutch cards.

Which cards are these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=46052) on the Steve Jackson games forums, the four Dutch exclusive cards are Verwilderd, Inburgeringscursus, Ontlastingsdienst, and De Dodenrit.

Note that the linked post listed one of the cards simply as `Dodenrit` while [this image](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/396340/munchkin-koethulhu) on BoardGameGeek shows it as `De Dodenrit` - so I can't guarantee the listed names are 100% complete, or if there a slight difference in versions between the two sources.